# iPhone Contact Syncing

Tags: iphone

Everytime I sync my iPhone, any contacts I have deleted from my iPhone reappear, like the old contacts are added back. New contacts remain.

Comment: To what kind of system do you sync? Mac? Windows? Something else perhaps even? If Windows, what kind of address book do you use there?

Comment: To the users voting to close: iPhone contacts are almost always synced with a desktop computer, which is **on topic** as per the FAQ: *"...except insofar as they interface with your computer"*. We don't have enough information yet to determine whether it's on or off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to reset Sync services. See http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1627

Answer (score 0):

Because your last backup has been used when you plug in your phone. Try moving the backup file to another folder (just in case you may need it), then delete the contacts you want to delete on your phone.

Once you got rid of the contacts you wanted to remove, create a new backup.

This should stop adding the contacts when syncing.